# CSS is not working on all pages in Google App Engine (python)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a blog and I have an issue with a page that I use to show an entire post. My main page is at "/" and the post page is at "/post/(post_id)" and both of them extends from "base.html" where I included all my css files (bootstrap). The css styling is working on all my blog pages, except that post page. If I look at that page's source, the css is there, included in the header, but still, it's not working. If I change that post page from "/post/(post_id)" to "/(post_id)" it works fine. Do you have any ideas about what might cause this issue?

Comment: I am guessing you have a relative path to css. Change it to absolute.

Comment: Please do post your HTML, as well as URL of the HTML and CSS when you ask why the link does not work.

Comment: It works with the absolute paths. I didn't know about this stuff so I googled it. Thanks!